# In-place inversion of large matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, matrices

In [Solving very large matrices in "pieces"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/solving-very-large-matrices-in-pieces) there is a way shown to solve matrix inversion in pieces. Is it possible to apply the method in-place?

I am refering to the answer in the referenced question that starts with:

$\textbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}&\textbf{F}\\\\ \textbf{G}&\textbf{H}\end{pmatrix}$

And computes the inverse via:

$\textbf{A}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}+\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{S}^{-1}\\\\ -\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&\textbf{S}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$, where $\textbf{S} = \textbf{H}-\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}$

Edit 05.10.2017:
Terrence Tao makes use of the same in a recent blog post: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/09/16/inverting-the-schur-complement-and-large-dimensional-gelfand-tsetlin-patterns/ , and puts it in relation to a "Schur complement".

Comment: It is possible to obtain the LU factorization "in place", at least for a diagonally dominant matrix.  You can then do the solve/backsolve calculations on the constant vector (right-hand side of the linear system) "in place" as well.  Would this be of interest?

Comment: I think the bottleneck is a way to do matrix multiplication in-place.  I don't know how to do that, say for a square matrix times a vector, overwriting the vector.  But if we could do that, then the referenced method seems to lend itself by recursion to an in-place matrix inversion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We suppose an (m+n) by (m+n) matrix $\textbf{A}$ with block partition:

$\textbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}&\textbf{F}\\\\ \textbf{G}&\textbf{H}\end{pmatrix}$

A sequence of steps can be outlined, invoking recursively an in-place matrix inversion and other steps involving in-place matrix multiplication.

Some but not all of these matrix multiplication operations would seem to require additional memory to be "temporarily" allocated in between recursive calls to the in-place matrix inversion.  At bottom we will argue that needed additional memory is linear, e.g. size m+n.

`1.` The first step is recursively to invert in-place matrix $\textbf{E}$:

$\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}&\textbf{F}\\\\ \textbf{G}&\textbf{H}\end{pmatrix}$

Of course to make that work requires the leading principal minor $\textbf{E}$ to be nonsingular.

`2.` The next step is to multiply $\textbf{E}^{-1}$ times block submatrix $\textbf{F}$ and negate the result:

$\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}&-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\\\\ \textbf{G}&\textbf{H}\end{pmatrix}$

Note that the matrix multiplication and overwriting in this step can be performed one column of $\textbf{F}$ at a time, something we'll revisit in assessing memory requirements.

`3.` Next multiply $\textbf{G}$ times the previous result $-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}$ and add it to the existing block submatrix $\textbf{H}$:

$\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}&-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\\\\ \textbf{G}&\textbf{H}-\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\end{pmatrix}$

This step can also be performed one column at a time, and because the results are accumulated in the existing block submatrix $\textbf{H}$, no additional memory is needed.

Note that what has now overwritten $\textbf{H}$ is $\textbf{S}=\textbf{H}-\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}$.

`4. & 5.` The next two steps can be done in either order.  We want to multiply block submatrix $\textbf{G}$ on the right by $\textbf{E}^{-1}$, and we also want to recursively invert in-place the previous result $\textbf{S}$.  After doing both we have:

$\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}&-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\\\\ \textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&\textbf{S}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$

Note that the matrix multiplication and overwriting of $\textbf{G}$ can be done one row at a time.

`6.` Next we should multiply these last two results, overwriting $\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}$ with $\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}$ and negating that block:

$\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}&-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\\\\ -\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&\textbf{S}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$

`7.`  We are on the home stretch now!  Multiply the two off-diagonal blocks and add that to the diagonal block containing $\textbf{E}^{-1}$:

$\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}+\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\\\\ -\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&\textbf{S}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$

`8.`  Finally we multiply the block containing $-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}$ on the right by $\textbf{S}^{-1}$, something that can be done one row at a time:

$\textbf{A}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{E}^{-1}+\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{S}^{-1}\\\\ -\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}&\textbf{S}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$

**Requirements for additional memory:**

A temporary need for additional memory arises when we want to do matrix multiplication and store the result back into the location of one of the two factors.

Such a need arises in step 2. when forming $\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}$, in step 4. (or 5.) when forming $\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}$, in step 6. when forming $\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}$, and in step 8. when forming $-\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{S}^{-1}$.

Of course other "temporary" allocations are hidden in recursive calls to in-place inversion in step 1. and step 4.&5. when matrices $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{S}$ are inverted.

In each case the allocated memory can be freed (or reused) after one column or one row of a required matrix multiplication is performed, because the overwriting can be done one column or one row at a time following its computation.  The overhead for such allocations is limited to size m+n, or even max(m,n), i.e. a linear overhead in the size of $\textbf{A}$.

Comment: How would you handle the case where either $\textbf{E}$ or $\textbf{S}$ are zero matrices?

Comment: @howardh: If $\mathbf{E}$ is the zero matrix in some step, the recursion outlined above fails (since that block would not be invertible), and similarly for $\mathbf{S}$ a zero matrix (or more generally, a singular one).  The situation is similar to Gauss elimination without pivoting.  The algorithm is certainly less robust because of its "in-place" limitation.  If it were known in advance that $\mathbf{E}$ is zero, then the block structure of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ would also contain a zero block (in the lower right corner).  Please post a new question if the details would interest you.

Comment: How would you invert $\textbf{S}=\textbf{H}-\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}$ (i.e. inverting the Schur complement of $\textbf{E}$)? One way would be to use Woodbury identity, but we would end up with "**the chicken or the egg dilemma**", since $\textbf{S}^{-1}= \textbf{H}^{-1}+\textbf{H}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{T}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{H}^{-1}$ where $\textbf{T}^{-1}= \textbf{E}^{-1}+\textbf{E}^{-1}\textbf{F}\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{G}\textbf{E}^{-1}$.

Comment: See the link in the body of the Question for the problem of inverting a matrix "in pieces".  The focus here is not the recursive calls themselves but rather the need for allocating additional memory to manage those recursive calls successfully.  Since $\mathbf S$ is smaller than $\mathbf A$, performing an additional in-place inversion is possible without invoking a circular "chicken or egg" dependence.  We've already called for something like that in step 1, where $\mathbf E$ gets inverted in-place.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.